# LUA IPv6 to Long

Tags: c, lua, openresty

Using the module below, I can long IPv4 address. How can I do the same for IPv6?

```
function ip2long(ip)
    local inp = ffi.new("struct in_addr[1]")
    if C.inet_aton(ip, inp) ~= 0 then
        return tonumber(C.ntohl(inp[0].s_addr))
    end
    return nil
end

function long2ip(long)
    if type(long) ~= "number" then
        return nil
    end
    local addr = ffi.new("struct in_addr")
    addr.s_addr = C.htonl(long)
    return ffi.string(C.inet_ntoa(addr))
end
```

https://github.com/agentzh/lua-php-utils/blob/master/php/utils.lua

Comment: IPv6 is 16 bytes long. `long int` is shorter. And `__int128` is not exactly supported yet.

Comment: ip2long() converts IP to a Lua number (double). it is not possible to express IPv6 using one  Lua number